# Could not process key 'dataSource' in PropertyOverrideConfigurer - Invalid key 'dataSource': expected 'beanName.property

Tags: javascript, oracle, datasource, sailpoint

I am installing sailpoint in oracle and the properties configure is:

```
##### Data Source Properties #####
dataSource.maxWaitMillis=10000
dataSource.maxTotal=50
dataSource.minIdle=5
#dataSource.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=300000
#dataSource.maxOpenPreparedStatements=-1

dataSource.username=identityiq
dataSource.password=1:ACP:VHGrGBFYLIDoRdWK2VUg0s0hZuSraCRCrW0MKqWumLc=

##### Oracle #####
## URL Format: dataSource.url=jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:<username/password>@<database>:<port>:<sid>
###dataSource=jdbc:oracle:thin:identityiq/Password*1234@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = 10.0.160.58) (PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = IDENTITYIQ)));
dataSource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@nediacredhat8.dodiis.ic.gov:1521:identityiq
dataSource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
sessionFactory.hibernateProperties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
activeMQMessageServiceManager.activemqJdbcAdapter=org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.OracleJDBCAdapter
```

when I run the iiq console, I get the error:

```
iiq.hostname : sailpoint_hostname-console
2023-11-22T08:18:10,753  WARN main springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:559 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'versionChecker' defined in class path resource [configBeans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to check IdentityIQ database version: Unable to connect to: jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle_hostname:1521:identityiq
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'versionChecker' defined in class path resource [configBeans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to check IdentityIQ database version: Unable to connect to: jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle_hostname:1521:identityiq
```

even I hardcode the password in the properties file and/or using tnsname connection:

```
##### Data Source Properties #####
dataSource.maxWaitMillis=10000
dataSource.maxTotal=50
dataSource.minIdle=5
#dataSource.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=300000
#dataSource.maxOpenPreparedStatements=-1

##dataSource.username=identityiq
##dataSource.password=1:ACP:VHGrGBFYLIDoRdWK2VUg0s0hZuSraCRCrW0MKqWumLc=

##### Oracle #####
## URL Format: dataSource.url=jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:<username/password>@<database>:<port>:<sid>
dataSource=jdbc:oracle:thin:identityiq/Password*1234@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = oracle_hostname) (PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = IDENTITYIQ)));
###dataSource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:identityiq/Password*1234@oracle_hostname:1521:identityiq
dataSource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
sessionFactory.hibernateProperties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
activeMQMessageServiceManager.activemqJdbcAdapter=org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.OracleJDBCAdapter
```

using the tnsname connection, I got error:

```
iiq.hostname : sailpoint_hostname-console
2023-11-22T08:29:41,533  WARN main springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:559 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not process key 'dataSource' in PropertyOverrideConfigurer; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Invalid key 'dataSource': expected 'beanName.property'
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not process key 'dataSource' in PropertyOverrideConfigurer; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Invalid key 'dataSource': expected 'beanName.property
```

'
How to connect sailpoint on Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

The line with the JDBC URL starts with 'dataSource='. This should be 'dataSource**.url**='. So, it's missing a keyword.